# error free(): invalid next size (fast) in SQL request in microcontroller

Tags: sql-server, codesys

I make SQL request in SQL Server in microcontroller SPK and I get an error:

> Invalid next size (fast)

I use codesys v3.5 sp17 path3+.

I get the error "invalid next size (fast)" with report from SQL Server.

I also get the following message

> 17 rows affected

but last lines are cut off.